# Raspberry pi 3 Whatsapp

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

I installed whatsapp on raspberry pi 3, but can't find information how I can use it in python script. I want to use it for door open/close python script. I have script working with email, but email isn't so fast, anyone have something working with whatsapp or telegrambot??? any advices Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you have two solutions yowsup library & celenium library.

yowsup is painful, as whatsapp updated their security bugs and so on. I used it a couple of years ago to do basic home automation. you must consider some steps before, like using the phone number with a real whatsapp for more than 12 hours to avoid ban

regarding selenium it is a web automation library actually, that you can use to control the web version of whatsapp. it is along way, for just some motors however,  it will pay back as you have leaned an important library, and you'll be capable of automating most websites including whatsapp.

good luck

Comment: I just get it work with telegram.

Comment: telegram is much better, it have built-in support for bots and automation. that is great hope your project succeed

Comment: @AurimasŠiaulys Please make a short answer about your solution and accept it after two days. Only accepting an answer will finish your question and it will not pop up again months for months.